# python use opencv get an error

Tags: python, opencv

When I use the opencv with the python, I always get an error.
I set the environment like this:

1. install the python "python-2.7.5.msi"
2. install the numpy "numpy-MKL-1.7.1.win32-py2.7.exe"
3. install the opencv "opencv-python-2.4.6.win32-py2.7.exe"

Everything is OK. I test it using the following code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('lena.bmp')
cv2.show('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But I got an error as follow:

```
 File "E:\Python\cv2.py", line 1, in <module>
         import cv2
 File "E:\Python\cv2.py", line 2, in <module>
      img = cv2.imread('lena.bmp') 
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'
```

Why? But when I print "import cv2" in the IDLE, I didn't get any error.

Comment: Did you name the file you were testing it in "cv2.py"?

Comment: Yes, I named the file cv2.py. I have renamed it and now it's successful, thank you very much@JeremyBentham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I guess you imported your file, ie the file you are writing. cause the file is using the name "cv2.py" as it suggested. you`d better change the filename.